# How do you set desktop background with nemo configured to manage the desktop, in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nemo

If Nemo is configured to manage the desktop:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons true
```

it does not respect the **System settings -> Appearance -> Background** and shows some default Ubuntu image.

This used to work in 14.04.

Is there any way to force the background?

Answer (score 0):

[WEB UPD8](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/nemo-with-unity-patches-available-for.html) provides a PPA for a patched version of Nemo that automatically provides the other components for the desktop background and other integrations necessary for Unity.

The link to the PPA and detailed instructions is:
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html

The install steps are:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/nemo
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nemo nemo-fileroller
```